# Como cambiar el valor de los inputs cada que selecciono un checkbox?

Tags: javascript, json, checkbox

Tengo este archivo json

{"nombre_form": "Norah Tudela", "nombre_nit_form": "Norah Tudela", "nits_form": "68580043", "nits": [{"nit": "123456789", "razon_social": "NORAH TUDELA"}, {"nit": "888", "razon_social": "KFC"}]}

Y cada vez que selecciono un checkbox se deberia cambiar el input con los datos que tiene cada checkbox
Tengo una funcion javascript que lo hace, pero solo inserta el ultimo valor

```
function datos_ckeckbox(){
                                                                        
                                        
                                        var telefono=document.getElementById("celulartxt").value;
                                        var urlcadena = 'http://localhost:27012/cria/info_cliente' + '?telf=' + telefono;
                                        console.log(urlcadena);
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        url: urlcadena,
                                                        success: function(respuesta) {
                                                            console.log(respuesta);
                                                            var strings = JSON.stringify(respuesta);
                                                            console.log(JSON.stringify(respuesta));
                                                            window.respuesta=strings;
                                                            var obj = JSON.parse(respuesta);
                                                            console.log(obj);
                                                            window.respuesta=obj;

                                                            function rellenar_checkbox(id, obj) {
                                                                let elem = document.getElementById(id);
                                                                
                                                                while (elem.firstChild) {
                                                                    elem.removeChild(elem.lastChild);
                                                                }
                                                                
                                                                obj.forEach(dato => {
                                                                    
                                                                    let label = document.createElement("label");
                                                                    let input = document.createElement("input");
                                                                    
                                                                    input.type = "checkbox";
                                                                    
                                                                    label.innerText = dato.nit + dato.razon_social;
                                                                    input.value = dato.nit;
                                                                    
                                                                    label.prepend(input);
                                                                    
                                                                    elem.appendChild(label);

                                                                    document.getElementById("numero_factura").value=dato.nit;
                                                                });
                                                                }
                                                                rellenar_checkbox("checkBundle", obj.nits);

                                                        },
                                                        error: function() {
                                                            console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                        
                                        }
```

Por ultimo este es el html donde se visualizan los campos

```
<div class="wrap-input100">
                                            <span class="label-input100"><b>DATOS PARA LA
                                                    FACTURA</b></span>
                                            <br />
                                            <br />
                                            <span class="label-input100">Nombre</span>
                                            <input class="input100" type="text" name="nombre_factura"
                                                id="nombre_factura" placeholder="Nombre para la Factura" />

                                            <span class="label-input100">Nro Carnet/Nro NIT</span>
                                            <input class="input100" type="number" name="numero_factura"
                                                id="numero_factura" placeholder="Nro de documento a facturar" />

                                            <span class="label-input100">Elija número de nit existente para su factura</span>
                                                <input type="button" id="popupbutton" onclick="datos_ckeckbox()"/>
                                            <ul id="checkBundle">

                                            </ul>

                                        </div>
```

[image: Adjunto una foto, ya que una imagen dice mas que mil palabras]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esta seria mi forma de hacerlo, espero te sea de utilidad
Estoy partiendo del hecho que ya se tiene el json en forma de array

```
var data = {
    "nombre_form": "Norah Tudela",
    "nombre_nit_form": "Norah Tudela",
    "nits_form": "68580043",
    "nits": [
        {
            "nit": "123456789",
            "razon_social": "NORAH TUDELA"
        },
        {
            "nit": "888",
            "razon_social": "KFC"
        }
    ]
};
var check_bundle = document.getElementById('checkBundle'); 
var nombre_factura = document.getElementById('nombre_factura');
var numero_factura = document.getElementById('numero_factura')
var nits = data['nits'];
nits.forEach( (elements) => {
    let label = document.createElement('label');
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    //EL tipo de boton lo he cambiado a radio
    //porque entiendo que solo se quiere una sola opcion
    input.type = 'radio';
    input.name = 'nit';
    //Le he añadido un listener para que cuando se haga click se realize el cambio en 
    //los inputs
    input.addEventListener('click',() => {
        nombre_factura.value = elements['razon_social'];
        numero_factura.value = elements['nit'];
    });
    label.innerText = elements['nit'] + ' ' + elements['razon_social'];
    check_bundle.append(input);
    check_bundle.append(label);
    
});
```